# Direct2D Tutorial Window No-Show

Tags: c++, windows, direct2d

I'm trying to use MSDN's Direct2D basic tutorial, but the window won't show up, it output's the normal debug info, but no window. I've tried playing about with the WinMain() parameters and the ShowWindow() function, but it still refuses to work. Allso in the debug info there's this, but i don't think it's relevant. \NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Here's the code.

```
#include "RenderHeader.h"

//Main window function.
int WINAPI WinMain(
HINSTANCE /* hInstance */,
HINSTANCE /* hPrevInstance */,
LPSTR /* lpCmdLine */,
int /* nCmdShow */)
{
    // Use HeapSetInformation to specify that the process should
    // terminate if the heap manager detects an error in any heap used
    // by the process.
    // The return value is ignored, because we want to continue running in the
    // unlikely event that HeapSetInformation fails.

    HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);

    if (SUCCEEDED(CoInitialize(NULL)))
    {
        {
        GameRender app;

        if (SUCCEEDED(app.Initialize()))
        {
            //Runs the application message loop.
        app.RunMessageLoop();
        }
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}

GameRender::GameRender() :
    m_hwnd(NULL),
    m_pDirect2DFactory(NULL),
    m_pRenderTarget(NULL),
    m_pLightSlateGrayBrush(NULL),
    m_pCornflowerBlueBrush(NULL)
{
}

GameRender::~GameRender()
{
    SafeRelease(&m_pDirect2DFactory);
    SafeRelease(&m_pRenderTarget);
    SafeRelease(&m_pLightSlateGrayBrush);
    SafeRelease(&m_pCornflowerBlueBrush);
}



HRESULT GameRender::Initialize()
{
    HRESULT hRes;

    /* Initialize device-indpendent resources, such
     as the Direct2D factory.*/
    hRes = CreateDeviceIndependantResources();

    if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
    {
        WNDCLASSEX Window = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) } ;
        Window.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        Window.lpfnWndProc = GameRender::WndProc;
        Window.cbClsExtra = 0;
        Window.cbWndExtra = sizeof(LONG_PTR);
        Window.hInstance = HINST_THISCOMPONENT;
        Window.hbrBackground = NULL;
        Window.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        Window.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        Window.lpszClassName = L"D2DDemoApp";

        RegisterClassEx(&Window);

        /* Because the CreateWindow function takes its size in pixels,
         obtain the system DPI and use it to scale the window size.*/
        FLOAT DpiX, DpiY;

        /* The factory returns the current system DPI. This is also the value it will use
         to create its own windows.*/
        m_pDirect2DFactory->GetDesktopDpi(&DpiX, &DpiY);

        //Create Window
        m_hwnd = CreateWindow(L"D2PDemoApp", 
            L"Direct 2D Demo App", 
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, 
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            static_cast<UINT>(ceil(640.f * DpiX / 96.f)),
            static_cast<UINT>(ceil(480.f * DpiY / 96.f)),
            NULL, 
            NULL,
            HINST_THISCOMPONENT, 
            this);

        hRes = m_hwnd ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
        if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
        {
        ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        UpdateWindow(m_hwnd);
        }
    }
    return hRes;
}



HRESULT GameRender::CreateDeviceIndependantResources()
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    //Create a direct2D Factory
hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &m_pDirect2DFactory);
return hr;
}

HRESULT GameRender::CreateDeviceDependantResources()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if(!&m_pRenderTarget)
    {
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(m_hwnd, &rc);

D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

//Create a render target.
hr = m_pDirect2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(m_hwnd, size), &m_pRenderTarget);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Create a gray brush.
            hr = m_pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(
                D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::LightSlateGray),
                &m_pLightSlateGrayBrush);
        }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Create a blue brush.
            hr = m_pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(
                D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::CornflowerBlue),
                &m_pCornflowerBlueBrush
                );
        }
    }
    return hr;
}

void GameRender::DiscardDeviceResources()
{
    SafeRelease(&m_pRenderTarget);
    SafeRelease(&m_pLightSlateGrayBrush);
    SafeRelease(&m_pCornflowerBlueBrush);
}
void GameRender::RunMessageLoop()
{
    MSG Message;
    while (GetMessage(&Message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Message);
        DispatchMessage(&Message);
    }
}
HRESULT GameRender::OnDraw()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    hr = CreateDeviceDependantResources();

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        m_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();

        m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());

        m_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));

        D2D1_SIZE_F rtSize = m_pRenderTarget->GetSize();

        // Draw a grid background.
        int width = static_cast<int>(rtSize.width);
        int height = static_cast<int>(rtSize.height);

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 10)
        {
            m_pRenderTarget->DrawLine(
                D2D1::Point2F(static_cast<FLOAT>(x), 0.0f),
                D2D1::Point2F(static_cast<FLOAT>(x), rtSize.height),
                m_pLightSlateGrayBrush,
                0.5f
                );
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y += 10)
        {
            m_pRenderTarget->DrawLine(
                D2D1::Point2F(0.0f, static_cast<FLOAT>(y)),
                D2D1::Point2F(rtSize.width, static_cast<FLOAT>(y)),
                m_pLightSlateGrayBrush,
                0.5f
                );
        }

        // Draw two rectangles.
        D2D1_RECT_F rectangle1 = D2D1::RectF(
            rtSize.width/2 - 50.0f,
            rtSize.height/2 - 50.0f,
            rtSize.width/2 + 50.0f,
            rtSize.height/2 + 50.0f
            );

        D2D1_RECT_F rectangle2 = D2D1::RectF(
            rtSize.width/2 - 100.0f,
            rtSize.height/2 - 100.0f,
            rtSize.width/2 + 100.0f,
            rtSize.height/2 + 100.0f
            );


        // Draw a filled rectangle.
        m_pRenderTarget->FillRectangle(&rectangle1, m_pLightSlateGrayBrush);

        // Draw the outline of a rectangle.
        m_pRenderTarget->DrawRectangle(&rectangle2, m_pCornflowerBlueBrush);

        hr = m_pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
    }

    if (hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET)
    {
        hr = S_OK;
        DiscardDeviceResources();
    }

    return hr;
}

void GameRender::OnResize(UINT width, UINT height)
{
    if (m_pRenderTarget)
    {
        // Note: This method can fail, but it's okay to ignore the
        // error here, because the error will be returned again
        // the next time EndDraw is called.
        m_pRenderTarget->Resize(D2D1::SizeU(width,
        height));
    }
}
LRESULT CALLBACK GameRender::WndProc(
HWND hwnd,
UINT message,
WPARAM wParam,
LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT result = 0;

    if (message == WM_CREATE)
    {
        LPCREATESTRUCT pcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam;
        GameRender *pGameRender = (GameRender *)pcs->lpCreateParams;

        ::SetWindowLongPtrW(
            hwnd,
            GWLP_USERDATA,
            PtrToUlong(pGameRender)
            );

        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        GameRender *pGameRender = reinterpret_cast<GameRender *>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(
            ::GetWindowLongPtrW(
                hwnd,
                GWLP_USERDATA
                )));

        bool wasHandled = false;

        if (pGameRender)
        {
            switch (message)
            {
            case WM_SIZE:
                {
                    UINT width = LOWORD(lParam);
                    UINT height = HIWORD(lParam);
                    pGameRender->OnResize(width, height);
                }
                result = 0;
                wasHandled = true;
                break;

            case WM_DISPLAYCHANGE:
                {
                    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
                }
                result = 0;
                wasHandled = true;
                break;

            case WM_PAINT:
                {
                    pGameRender->OnDraw();
                    ValidateRect(hwnd, NULL);
                }
                result = 0;
                wasHandled = true;
                break;

            case WM_DESTROY:
                {
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                }
                result = 1;
                wasHandled = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!wasHandled)
        {
            result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "RenderHeader.h" exists in your project's directory and it includes the windows header, then your problem is that you're not passing WinMain the variables it needs to function. 'HINSTANCE', 'LPSTR' and 'int' are all variable types, but you need to give them a name, otherwise they don't exist and the function won't work.
So this would be right

```
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                    int       uCmdShow )
{
    // The rest of the code
}
```

The names of the variables are commented out on the code in your question :P